# InDesign: How to stretch anchored object with text frame?

Tags: adobe-indesign, resize

In InDesign, I have a text frame with yellow line at its left border as an anchored object. The text frame is set to resize vertically to fit its contents, and as it grows, I would like for the yellow line to grow with it and match its height. If this is possible, how can I do it?

[image: Anchored object and text frame]

The reason I'm not making this adjustment manually is that I have 80 pages of content, each with three of these lines, linked to XML documents. I also looked into created these lines as borders on text frames and tables, but it appears neither can style border segments individually.

[image: Anchored object options]

Comment: This will probably be doable [in InDesign CC2018](https://avxhome.unblocked.pro/ebooks/InDesign-CC-2018-New-Features-65116243.html) (see third from bottom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also looked into created these lines as borders on text frames and **tables**, but it appears neither can style border segments individually.

I think you were in the right direction when talking about tables. As a matter of fact, you can style a single border using the cell options.

Put your text into a single cell and use Cell style to style up your cell.

See example below:

[image]

Comment: Good call. For some reason I was thinking width, not height.